# Не добавляется appcompat в проект

Tags: android, java, android-studio

Замучила ошибка, делаю проект, gradle не использую.

```
Error:(14, -1) android-apt-compiler: styles.xml:14: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
```

Куда только и как я не добавлял эти библиотеки, все равно вылазит ошибка.

Comment: Тут [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support] смотрели?

Comment: мне кажется, что версия аппкомпата не та... Всегда используйте последнюю версию SDK и всех библиотек

Comment: @ЮрийСПб
Да я все это пробовал, тем более там под eclipse
я же использую android studio, на эклипсе я бы это решил, но код писали под android studio, и мне надо запустить и собрать проект, чужой ((( но у автора все работает.

@metalurgus свежеустановленная студия, самый последний sdk и самые последние компоненты к нему.

Пробовал использовать gradle, но тогда рушится в других местах  (((

Comment: А опишите, как вы добавляли библиотек в проект. Подобная ошибка может, например, возникать, если вы добавили только *.jar, но не импортировали модуль в проект, или не выставили модулю, что он является библиотекой.